# count out grid item without moving the element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to use CSS grid one a specific container. But there is one direct  descendant i don't want to use as a grid-item. Is there a property or method to do this? I don't want to change the location in my HTML.

The h2 element i don't want to use as a grid-item.

```
        <article id="main-diagram"> //CSS grid
        <h2>Ingescheven ouders</h2> // this is the descendant
        <ul id="diagram-times">
            <li>18:00</li>
            <li>19:00</li>
            <li>20:00</li>
            <li>21:00</li>
        </ul>
        <section class="main-diagram-1">
            <p>30%</p>
        </section>
        <section class="main-diagram-2">
            <p>40%</p>
        </section>
        <section class="main-diagram-3">
            <p>50%</p>
        </section>
        <section class="main-diagram-4">
            <p>60%</p>
        </section>
        <ul id="diagram-places">
            <li>12/30</li>
            <li>14/32</li>
            <li>10/20</li>
            <li>32/33</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
```

Thanks!

ps: there is no css yet

Comment: on idea is to make it span all the first row then you start your grid from the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css property `grid-template-areas:` to specify which elements should appear, and where.

Example using your code:

```
#diagram-times {grid-area: topleft}
.main-diagram-1 {grid-area: topright;}
.main-diagram-2 {grid-area: botleft;}
.main-diagram-3 {grid-area: botright;}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "topleft topright"
  "botleft botright"
}
```

[Great guide on grid.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)